# Adobe AIR unrestricted access... how do i restrict it?

Tags: javascript, dialog, air, installation

Im programming my first application in Adobe AIR but i've noticed that on the install dialog it says my program has unrestricted access to the filesystem and such and i think that might scare potential users.

Is there any way i can restrict it so that message doesnt show up in the dialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. There's no way for you to hide the warning - and that's a good thing, because there's also no way (yet) to make an AIR app that *doesn't* have full access to the user's file system. In theory, any AIR app *could* delete random files without telling the user, so the warning is quite necessary. I believe that restricted AIR apps are something Adobe is planning for the future, but nothing so far.

The only think you can control in that dialog is, if you sign your app with a certificate that is trusted by the user, then your name will appear in the "Publisher" field. Otherwise it will be "unknown".

(Note that if the user does install your app, then in the future when they upgrade, you can substitute a custom dialog. But for the initial install you are stuck with the standard one.)

Comment: But, I've seen apps with Publisher known, that do NOT display unrestricted access

Comment: I think that native installer (.exe / .dmg) doesn't display that unrestricted access message.